# conditions on django generic detailview

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to show a post detail view only when post.status=='pub'. I did it in list view with overriding get_queryset method but how can i do the same with detail view?

I want the detail view to return 404 when post.status=='drf'

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('pub', 'عمومی'),
        ('drf', 'پیش نویس')
    )


    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='عنوان')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='توضیحات')
    body = RichTextField(verbose_name='بدنه')
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), models.CASCADE, verbose_name='نویسنده')
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='زمان ایجاد')
    datetime_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='آخرین ویرایش')
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=3, verbose_name='حالت انتشار')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'پست'
```

PostListView and PostDetailView

```py
class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'pages/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(status='pub')


class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'pages/post_detail.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reading django code and i found a method called get in generic.DetailView parent class. i found a method called get which was getting the context and rendering it. I overrode it and added my conditions. here is my new detail view:

```py
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'pages/post_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

        if self.object.status == 'pub' or self.request.user.has_perm('posts.view_draft_post'):
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        else:
            raise Http404
```

I should mention that I also added a new permission to my model:

```py
# inside Post model:
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'پست'
        permissions = (
            ("can_view_draft_post", "دیدن پست های پیش نویس"),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the "model" property by the "queryset" property and set the filter you want. [Django documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects)

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
  queryset = Post.objects.filter(status='pub')
  context_object_name = 'post'
  template_name = 'pages/post_detail.html'
```

Comment: your answer didn't work for me, but i tried reading django.views.generic.detail.BaseDetailView and i saw that i can override get method and add my own processing in it. I'll share my solution as a new answer.